# Possible implementation of Promise.any on JS

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, v8

In Promise.race the promise returns as soon that the primary promise returns. In Promise.all returns when all promises resolves, but lasts one problem. If any of all promises rejects all others will be rejected.

Instead of it, exists a [proposal](https://v8.dev/features/promise-combinators) for a Promise.any, the returns every promise alone, independent of each other, short-circuiting on a rejection.

```
const logAfterWait = (seconds) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return setTimeout(() => resolve(console.log(`${time} time passed`)), seconds)
}) 

const watingList = [
    logAfterWait(convertToSeconds(10)),
    logAfterWait(convertToSeconds(30)),
    logAfterWait(convertToSeconds(5))
]

const logReading = async (fn) => {
    console.log(`${time}: reading file`)
    await fn()
}

const readFiles = (files) => Promise.all(watingList.map(logReading))
    .catch((error) => new Error(error))
```

The problem here is the block of event loop on the maping cause block on event loop on Promise.all, returning every results on the same time, differ from the expected result, that is, 5, 10, 30 seconds.

Can I avoid this situation on waitingList.map?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't get your question. What results *do you get* and what result *did you expect* ? And how is Promise.any related to that?

Comment: And there is no "block of IO" at all.

Comment: On Promise.all.

Comment: "*Promise.any, the returns every promise alone, independent of each other,*" - no, that's not what `Promise.any` does. It works just like `Promise.race`, except for short-circuiting on a rejection - it waits for the first fulfillment, and returns a single promise for that result.

Comment: There's missing a notation about that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consequently, I came to a conclusion. We create a resolver that is an Either monad(not a pure implementation of the Either monad) that returns [err, response] over a map function.

The catch blocks are necessary to avoid the Unhandled Promise Rejection Warning.

```js
const time = () => `${new Date().getHours()}:${new Date().getMinutes()}:${new Date().getSeconds()}`;

const sleep = (ms, pNumber) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    return pNumber < 3
        ? setTimeout(() => resolve(console.log(`${time()} time passed`)), ms)
        : reject(null)
    }).catch(null)


Promise.prototype.resolver = async (promise) => {
    this._result = await Promise.all([promise])[0];
    
    return this._result == null
        ? ["The time flies", promise]
        : [null, promise]
}

const watingList = [
    Promise.resolver(sleep(0, 0).catch(console.error)),
    Promise.resolver(sleep(3000, 1).catch(console.error)),
    Promise.resolver(sleep(5000, 2).catch(console.error)),
    Promise.resolver(sleep(5000, 3).catch(console.error))
]

const logReading = (list) => {
    return list.map(p => p.then(console.log(`${time()}: reading file`))
        .catch(console.log))
}

((read) => logReading(read))(watingList)
```

*PS:* *time* function differs from the expected because of the evaluate time.

---

- Resources can be found here:
  1 - https://frontendmasters.com/courses/hardcore-js-v2/either-monad/

Answer (score 1):

You can leverage the fact that `Promise.race` forms a monoid by creating a `Promise` that never settles:

```js
const empty = x => new Promise((res, rej) => x); // never settling promise

const ps = [
  Promise.reject(1).catch(empty),
  Promise.resolve(2).catch(empty),
  Promise.resolve(3).catch(empty)];

Promise.race(ps)
  .then(console.log); // 2
```

You need to attach a `catch` handler to each `Promise` in the array though. You can probably create a utility function that does this for you.

Comment: Hello @Iven, in the fact, the promises the never settles is not poiting in the direction of monads. 

[quote] ...the functions from a set into itself form a monoid with respect to function composition. More generally, in category theory, the morphisms of an object to itself form a monoid, and, conversely, a monoid may be viewed as a category with a single object. (Wikipedia/Monoid)[quote]

The function that is empty, doens't point to a group, yet, it points to another group, a group what we can call the never settled group.

Answer (score 0):

You could think of something like this:

```js
// a solution might just be not using async/await
const any = (promises) => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let errors = [];
  let resolved;
  
  const onFulfill = (value) => {
    // skip if already resolved
    if (resolved) { return; }
    resolved = true;
    
    // resolve with the first available value
    resolve(value);
  };
  
  const onError = (error) => {
    // skip if already resolved
    if (resolved) { return; }
    
    // collect error
    errors = errors.concat(error);
    
    // reject promise combinator if all promises are failed
    if (errors.length === promises.length) {
      reject(errors);
    }
  };
  
  return promises.forEach((promise) => promise.then(
    onFulfill,
    onError,
  ));
});

const sleep = (ms) => new Promise(r => setTimeout(() => r(ms), ms));
const err = (ms) => sleep(ms).then(() => Promise.reject(ms));

// it would log 2000, since it is the first to resolve
any([sleep(3000), err(100), sleep(2000)]).then(console.info)


// it would an array of 2 failures
any([err(50), err(60)]).catch(console.error)
```

---

> the block of IO

Note that there isn't any block of IO in javascript, the thread is just free to tackle any other task while waiting for the promises to be resolved.

Comment: Hi @Hitmands. The question is to log while resolves, instead of block every Promise until the last resolves. In this example the result is similar to Promise.race.